# Error AsyncTask #1

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask

Hi everyone I get this code from my mysql database

```
[{"u_id":"8","id":"8","name":"test1","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"loo\nlol","date":"2014-11-21","time":"18:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"},
{"u_id":"8","id":"9","name":"test9","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"test9\n","date":"2014-11-21","time":"19:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"}, 
{"u_id":"8","id":"10","name":"test10","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"lol","date":"2014-11-22","time":"19:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"},
{"u_id":"8","id":"11","name":"lol","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"","date":"2014-11-24","time":"18:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"}]
```

I was able to get it into my android application.

I insert the data into my listview.

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                Log.w("jsonArray:USER_ID", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("u_id"));
                Log.w("user_id:USER_ID", user_id);

                if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("u_id")==user_id)
                    own_event = true;
                else
                    own_event = false;

                Log.w("jsonArray", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());

                adapter.add(new DataProvider(own_event,
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"),
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"),
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"),
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("time"),
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("location_long"),
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("location_lati"),
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id")));
            }
```

Now when I run the application on my phone, I get this error.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       Process: com.myup2.up2, PID: 4240
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

But sometimes i dont even get an error and the application is running and showing the results.

```
11-26 15:31:27.892    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/params﹕ [user_id=8]
11-26 15:31:29.382    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/jsoninsideParser﹕ [{"u_id":"8","id":"8","eventname":"test1","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"loo\nlol","date":"2014-11-21","time":"18:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"},{"u_id":"8","id":"9","eventname":"test9","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"test9\n","date":"2014-11-21","time":"19:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"},{"u_id":"8","id":"10","eventname":"test10","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"lol","date":"2014-11-22","time":"19:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"},{"u_id":"8","id":"11","eventname":"lol","location_long":"10.01475","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"","date":"2014-11-24","time":"18:00:00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date_updated":"0000-00-00"}]
11-26 15:31:29.402    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/jsonArray:USER_ID﹕ 8
11-26 15:31:29.402    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/user_id:USER_ID﹕ 8
11-26 15:31:29.412    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/jsonArray﹕ {"id":"8","time":"18:00:00","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"loo\nlol","date_updated":"0000-00-00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date":"2014-11-21","u_id":"8","location_long":"10.01475","eventname":"test1"}
11-26 15:31:29.412    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/dataprovider_item_created﹕ test1
11-26 15:31:29.412    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/dataprovider_item_own_event﹕ false
11-26 15:31:29.412    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/jsonArray:USER_ID﹕ 8
11-26 15:31:29.412    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/user_id:USER_ID﹕ 8
11-26 15:31:29.422    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/jsonArray﹕ {"id":"9","time":"19:00:00","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"test9\n","date_updated":"0000-00-00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date":"2014-11-21","u_id":"8","location_long":"10.01475","eventname":"test9"}
11-26 15:31:29.422    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/dataprovider_item_created﹕ test9
11-26 15:31:29.422    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/dataprovider_item_own_event﹕ false
11-26 15:31:29.422    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/jsonArray:USER_ID﹕ 8
11-26 15:31:29.422    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/user_id:USER_ID﹕ 8
11-26 15:31:29.432    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/jsonArray﹕ {"id":"10","time":"19:00:00","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"lol","date_updated":"0000-00-00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date":"2014-11-22","u_id":"8","location_long":"10.01475","eventname":"test10"}
11-26 15:31:29.442    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/dataprovider_item_created﹕ test10
11-26 15:31:29.442    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/dataprovider_item_own_event﹕ false
11-26 15:31:29.442    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/jsonArray:USER_ID﹕ 8
11-26 15:31:29.442    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/user_id:USER_ID﹕ 8
11-26 15:31:29.452    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/jsonArray﹕ {"id":"11","time":"18:00:00","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"","date_updated":"0000-00-00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date":"2014-11-24","u_id":"8","location_long":"10.01475","eventname":"lol"}
11-26 15:31:29.452    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/dataprovider_item_created﹕ lol
11-26 15:31:29.452    6936-6966/com.myup2.up2 W/dataprovider_item_own_event﹕ false
```

When the error appears it shows me thses different places:

```
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver(){
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                listview.setSelection(adapter.getCount()-1);
            }
        });

@Override
    public void add(DataProvider object) {
        event_list.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }
```

But none of them really help

I dont even know where to start searching for the error. Maybe someone of you can help me on that.

Edit1:

It is always showing this error after the first entry is saved.

```
11-26 15:40:34.702    8062-8093/com.myup2.up2 W/jsonArray﹕{"id":"8","time":"18:00:00","location_lati":"53.57823","description":"loo\nlol","date_updated":"0000-00-00","date_created":"2014-11-20","date":"2014-11-21","u_id":"8","location_long":"10.01475","eventname":"test1"}
11-26 15:40:34.702    8062-8093/com.myup2.up2 W/dataprovider_item_created﹕ test1
11-26 15:40:34.702    8062-8093/com.myup2.up2 W/dataprovider_item_own_event﹕ false
11-26 15:40:34.702    8062-8093/com.myup2.up2 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41771ce0)
11-26 15:40:34.922    8062-8093/com.myup2.up2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
```

Edit2:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;

            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Home.this);
            String user_id = sp.getString("user_id", "anon");

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));

                Log.w("params", params.toString());

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        EVENTS_URL, "POST", params);



                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    Log.w("jsonArray:USER_ID", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("u_id"));
                    Log.w("user_id:USER_ID", user_id);

                    if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("u_id")==user_id)
                        own_event = true;
                    else
                        own_event = false;

                    Log.w("jsonArray", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());

                    adapter.add(new DataProvider(own_event,
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("eventname"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("time"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("location_long"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("location_lati"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id")));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
```

Comment: You can't change your adapter on `doInBackground`. Use `onPostExecute`

Comment: Could you provide your `doInBackground` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to move your method to the UI Thread. Which will be in your case `onPostExecute`, you can not modify views and such in a Background Thread.

```
protected ArrayList<DataProvider> doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;

            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Home.this);
            String user_id = sp.getString("user_id", "anon");

            ArrayList<DataProvider> dataProviders = new ArrayList<DataProvider>();

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));

                Log.w("params", params.toString());

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        EVENTS_URL, "POST", params);



                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    Log.w("jsonArray:USER_ID", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("u_id"));
                    Log.w("user_id:USER_ID", user_id);

                    if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("u_id")==user_id)
                        own_event = true;
                    else
                        own_event = false;

                    Log.w("jsonArray", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());

                    dataProviders.add(new DataProvider(own_event,
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("eventname"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("time"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("location_long"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("location_lati"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id")));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return dataProviders;

        }


    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<DataProvider> list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        adapter.add(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: So i call another function called "onPostExcecute" after I get the data from doinbackground?

Comment: You will have to override "onPostExecute" from AsyncTask, the same way you are overriding "doInBackground".

Comment: If you are new to using `AsyncTask`, you might find this helpful: http://hiqes.com/androids-asynctask-explained/

Comment: But how can I call the onPostExcecute after I run doInBackground?
Because first I need the response from the server and then change the ui

Comment: You don't call onPostExecute. After doInBackground is finished, onPostExecute will be called automagically.

Comment: I edited my answer for a better example how to do it! Take a look if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by manipulating your `ListView` from within your `doInBackground()` method. You'll need to move the manipulation into the `onPostExecute()` method. Be careful if you are creating the `DataSetObserver()` in your `doInBackground()` method as it is likely being bound to the background thread used by `AsyncTask` rather than the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can't and you should not modify the UI in a thread that is not the UI thread.

Do it like it :

```
protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args)
{
    // Check for success tag
    int success;

    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Home.this);
    String user_id = sp.getString("user_id", "anon");

    try {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));

        Log.w("params", params.toString());

        Log.d("request!", "starting");
        // getting product details by making HTTP request
        return jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(EVENTS_URL, "POST", params);    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And then :

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
    {
        Log.w("jsonArray:USER_ID", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("u_id"));
        Log.w("user_id:USER_ID", user_id);
        if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("u_id")==user_id)
            own_event = true;
        else
            own_event = false;

        Log.w("jsonArray", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());
        adapter.add(new DataProvider(own_event,
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"),
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("eventname"),
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"),
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("time"),
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("location_long"),
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("location_lati"),
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id")));
    }
    // Other stuff already in onPostExecute
}
```

Comment: This will only return the first element in the jsonarray!

Answer (score 0):

When updating things on the UI you have to update them on the UI Thread which is OnPostExecute in Async. Example.

```
public class UpdateUIThread extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    JSONArray array;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Do Network Stuff Here
    //array = (Insert String Here)
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject jObj  = array.getJSONObject(i);
      String string1 = jObj.getString("Name Of Object");
         adapter.add(new YourClass(string1));
        }
    }
}
```